# Dynamic SQL Insert: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I encounter some strange behavior with a dynamic SQL Query.
In a stored procedure I construct an insert query string out of multiple Strings. I execute the insert query in the SP like that - due to single nvarchar length restrictions.

```
EXEC(@QuerySelectPT+@QueryFromPT+@QueryFromPT)
```

If I print each part of the query, put these parts together and execute them manually in Management Studio the query works fine and inserts the data. But, if i execute the query in the EXEC() Method in the stored procedure, I get a

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Error Message.

Did multiple check on the amount, spelling of columns in my query and in my insert table, but I have not found any differences so far.

Any advices?

Comment: Do you have spaces between the string parts of your query?

Comment: Paste here whole strings. The information you provided is not enough. I made such errors myself - check again the final string

Comment: echo the `@QuerySelectPT+@QueryFromPT+@QueryFromPT` and what SQL it's generating

Comment: not possible it is for a client, but I have space between string parts and I have line breaks in the query. But the print of the whole query works

Comment: Can't see the whole query but this screams of sql injection vulnerability. It would be much better to parameterize your dynamic sql instead of just building up a string and executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your count of columns for insert are different from count of columns for select. Print the statement before exec and find the error.

Answer (score 0):

It as shot in the dark but seen you are telling the queries are valid and if you build the final query manually and it is working, the issue could be caused by string truncation.

Could you try:

```
EXEC(CAST(@QuerySelectPT AS VARCHAR(MAX))+@QueryFromPT+@QueryFromPT);
```

Also, as the `Management Studio`'s message tab and selects are limited to `4000` symbols I think, you can test if the whole query is assembled correctly like this:

```
SELECT CAST(@QuerySelectPT+@QueryFromPT+@QueryFromPT AS XML)
```